# Show popup instead of redirect to cart (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

my website: https://www.fermento24.com

I'd like to make it so that, when a client clicks on the add to cart button, instead of being redirected to cart I'd like for a popup with a resume of what's in the cart at the moment to appear.

Current code:

```html
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants clearfix" id="cart-form-4955949236295">                                    
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="32764390834247">  
        <a class="add-cart-btn">
          <i class="icon-basket"></i>
        </a>
      </form>
```

I wanted to add a popup that shows data similar to the popup of the minicar on top right, but I couldn't manage to do it. Anyone has suggestion on how to improve this feature?

Minicart code:

```html
<div class="has-items">
        <ul class="mini-products-list">  
          {% for item in cart.items %}
          <li class="item" id="cart-item-{{item.id}}">
            <a href="{{item.url}}" title="{{item.title}}" class="product-image">
              <img src="{{ item.image | product_img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{item.title}}"></a>
            <div class="product-details">
              <p class="product-name"><a href="{{item.url}}">{{ item.product.title }}
                {% if item.product.variants.size != 0 %}
                {% unless item.variant.title contains 'Default' %}
                {{ item.variant.title }}
                {% endunless %}
                {% endif %}</a></p>
              <div class="cart-collateral"><span class="price">{{item.price | money}}</span> x {{item.quantity}}</div>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" title="Remove This Item" class="btn-remove"><span class="zmdi zmdi-close"></span></a>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="summary">   
          <div>
          <hr style="visibility: visible;">
          <p class="stilefont"style="font-size:13px; text-align:center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;line-height: 1.3;"><b>Consegna gratuita</b> in 24/48h in <b>Italia</b> per ordini superiori ai 120€ altimetri il costo è di 10€.</p>
  <hr style="visibility: visible;">
<p class="stilefont"style="font-size:13px; text-align:center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;line-height: 1.3;"> <b>Consegna gratuita in giornata </b> in provincia di <a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" id="category-link" style="color: #000000; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: underline;"><b>Napoli*</b></a> e<a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" id="category-link" style="color: #000000; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: underline;"><b> Caserta*</b></a> per ordini superiori ai 25€ altrimenti il costo è di 3.50€</p>
   <hr style="visibility: visible;">
          </div>
          <p class="total">
            <span class="label">{{ 'cart.general.cart_total' | t }}</span>
            <span class="price">{{cart.total_price | money}}</span> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <button class="btn" onclick="window.location='/checkout'"><i class="icon-check"></i>{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</button>
          <button class="btn text-cart" onclick="window.location='/cart'"><i class="icon-basket"></i>{{ 'cart.general.view_cart' | t }}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what have you tried since the question is related to Javascript but no Javascript code is provided from your side? What is not clear and what issues do you face?

Comment: I'm not the greatest at Javascript. What I did was add the minicar part in a <span> with visibility: hidden; and used js to make it appear... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you using the [Winee](https://themeforest.net/item/winee-sectioned-wine-shopify-theme/22625078) Shopify premium theme template over your website?

You can check the [demo store](https://dt-wine.myshopify.com/) and you can check over the homepage, there is an AJAX cart that is inbuilt into this theme template.

You just need to check into documentation and enable it for the frontend.

Comment: I managed to add it and modify the popup, but now I'm having trouble when it adds a product. Example: https://p7dqjnwtg87p1h12-26803830855.shopifypreview.com/ 
as you can see if you scroll down and add a product, it'll show you what products are currently in cart, but if you add another product... it doesn't adjust.

Comment: Not sure, what is not working on your side, check the homepage and it works well and updates the cart data after adding the 2nd and  3rd product as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, my colleague changed something and didn't warn me. The problem I'm facing is mainly on mobile view. It should recap the products I've added to cart by telling me their name, but it works weirdly, doesn't work 100%